# send docker logs to other logdriver

Tags: docker

I am trying to send the logs from docker containers to another logdriver.

therefore I updated the docker service like so:

`docker service update --log-driver=loki --log-opt loki-url="http://srv-captain--loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push" --log-opt loki-retries=5 --log-opt loki-batch-size=400 srv-captain--pipapo`

when inspecting the container it seems to have worked:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' 964869a2d54a
loki
```

but logs are not transported to the loki instance. when I open a shell inside the container I want to get the logs from I can do this:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST -s "http://srv-captain--loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push" --data-raw  '{"streams": [{ "stream": { "foo": "bar2" }, "values": [ [ "1706627128000000000", "fizzbuzz" ] ] }]}'
```

which works. the "log" does show up in loki/grafana. so it seems that the log driver does not want to send the logs.

What is wrong here? any idea how and where I can debug why the logs are not sent from the container?

Thanks a lot for help!